# Equation of motion in 2D

Tags: vectors, projectile-motion

Whilst researching for a motion related software issue, I came across the following on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_linear_acceleration_in_any_direction)

"using 2D vectors, the equation $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$ becomes $v^2 = u^2 + 2a \bullet (r - r_0)$" (Paraphrased)

In summary, $as$ becomes $a \bullet s$

I have searched google, etc and found no references to why this is the case and I can't make sense of it.  I can also find no reference to how a scalar can be added to a vector.

My questions...

Is this correct or an error in the wikipedia page?

If correct, then

1. Why is this the case? - I can't see a reason why multiplication would not work for vectors as it does for scalars
2. How do I add a vector ($u^2$) to a scalar ($a \bullet \Delta r$)?

Cheers

Rob

Comment: I don't think $u^2$ is a vector. The square of a vector is generally not defined. I would say that $u$ is the length of a vector.

Comment: Hmm,  I'm sure I found reference to a way of doing this (resulting in a vector) but I can no longer find it, I suspect I mis-read the dot product.

Comment: $u^2$ is a square of a magnitude of vector $u$ (scalar product of $u$ and $u$)

Answer (score 1):

OK
I slightly misunderstood the concept of vector multiplication
The answer (as alluded to in the comments) is that **the equation is correct**.
$u^2$ is in fact a scalar, the entire equation returning a scalar value.
The whole equation makes sense but is actually of zero use to me in my context